# How Do Get My 2011 Hyundai Elantra Tachometer, Speedometer and Fuel Guage Display Working Again?

Tags: hyundai, elantra, odometer

My speedometer, tachometer and odometer all stopped working at the same time in my 2011 Hyundai Elantra (with manual transmission).

My analog tachometer and speedometer needles don't move. My digital odometer doesn't increment (for either of the trip counters nor the total number of miles.) My digital fuel gauge also shows no reading. (However my digital temperature gauge IS working.)

My check engine light does not come on and the lights to the gauges still will work fine. It's not a battery problem.

I hooked up a Bluetooth ODB2 dongle and ran the Android "Torque" app. I did not have any ODB2 errors and the app WAS able to show me my both my speed and RPMs in real time. (I'm not sure about the fuel level.)

The dealer said it would be about $500 just to trace the electrical system which is NOT a viable option. Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't mention doing anything to the car to cause the failure, so there is no way to suggest a fix for spontaneous failure, because there is no feasible way to determine what broke.

Comment: It sounds as though your dash has lost connection with your PCM. In a lot of cars, the temp gauge works off of a direct temperature sensor and not the computer (there would actually be two temp sensors, the other for the computer). Unfortunately, electrical problems are the hardest to diagnose, but remember, you don't have to take the vehicle to the dealer to get it worked on. Anyone can help you diagnose the issue, but it will take some work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your model car, but on older cars this would almost certainly be a burned-out fuse.  Ask around and/or do some online research for fuses in your car, or just take it to a local auto parts store and ask them if they will look at it.  It would take less than five minutes to find out.  If it's not that, then you need to go to the dealer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my 2013 Hyundai Elantra with the RPMS and loss of power, and it was the crankshaft position sensor that was faulty.