# 2013 Hyundai Elantra Speedometer, Odometer, Tach, and Gas gauge have stopped working

Tags: hyundai, speedometer, elantra, tachometer

I am new to this site and found that someone has previously asked this question, but they did not indicate if they ever found a fix for the problem. Their post is here [How Do Get My 2011 Hyundai Elantra Tachometer, Speedometer and Fuel Guage Display Working Again?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/how-do-get-my-2011-hyundai-elantra-tachometer-speedometer-and-fuel-guage-displa/50341?noredirect=1#comment87563_50341)

I am experiencing the same issue. I have a 2013 Hyundai Elantra which has been on the road since May 2012 and is about 6 months out of warranty and has around 55,000 KM on it (I think this is roughly 37,000 Miles) for a 5.5 year old car this is not much mileage.

In any case. Earlier this week my wife the primary driver of the vehicle noted that the speedometer, tach, and gas guage had stopped working. The speedometer and tach are 'analog' looking gauges bu the gas gauge is a digital gauge.

Upon checking further the odometer is not functioning and the trip meters are not incrementing. The average fuel economy is working, the temp gauge which is also digital is working. All idiot lights are working and light up as they should. The gear indicator is working. Cruise control works and the lights indicate it is working.

There is no sign of a check engine light being lit. So I presume no errors are being thrown. I found a post that mentions the vehicle speed sensor which is attached to the transmission as a possible option, which might make sense for the speedometer and tach but how does that sensor affect the fuel gauge? Plus if a VSS were to fail would that not throw an error code and cause the CEL to illuminate?

I've found other posts about pulling fuses or setting an on/off switch on the fuse panel to off for up to two minutes. I attempted removing and checking some fuses that appear to be related to the gauges; and I attempted setting the on/off switch to off for two minutes. The problem persists.

At this point I've seen this same problem described on a few different boards, but nobody has provided a specific fix. There have been suggestions, but not a specific answer.

In regards to the car, nothing has happened or has been done to the car. It had been sitting for 2-3 days last weekend (this being a Friday). We changed the tires to the winter set about a  month ago. But this is a full set of wheels and tires which have been used on the car for 4-5 seasons now.

I believe this is everything. I'm trying to be as thorough as possible and provide as many details of what I have read and what my problems are.

If anybody else out in Internet land has found a solution, I would like to know what the solution was.

Thank you in advance for any answers you can provide.

Kind Regards,
Chris

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which fuses did you check? What trim level is the car? There are two different instrument clusters for this car.

Comment: I believe this is a GL Trim level in Canada. Not sure if it matches the US Trim levels. On the door of the fuse panel in the dash there is a map of the fuses. In the first column the last one is a 10A fuse marked Cluster, The other was ACON/Switch 7.5 A, the last one of them top Row. I'd read something that these may be related to the gauges. The last one I think is more hvac related in the centre stack.

Comment: Here is a link to a photo of the fuse panel map in the vehicle. https://app.box.com/s/cfyni0hsaglkd2ndys59nakwjnt99ex5

Comment: Another update, today my wife (so this is a second hand report) indicates that the speedometer and gas gauge are working again. I haven't personally checked anything else. This would seem not to be a fuse. The only other thing that I can think of is that we had a lot of very heavy rain and strong winds around the time this occurred. Possibly there was water on or in something? I know one of my vehicles sounded it's panic alarm a few times after similar conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I seen on the all knowing internet. It could be something as stupid as a bad ground connection. The module that controls the instrument cluster is the the BCM (Body Control Module). Where the bad ground connection is...God knows.

Comment: This is partly true the IPS/BCM modules sends some, but not all signals to the ICM. The ICM takes some inputs directly from components and has some network lines to get things like VSS, body stuff like door switches and other things.